# On every click select next li tag

Tags: jquery

Being jQuery noob I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it:(
I have ul tag and couple li tags inside it. 
And I am trying to accomplish **this** : on **first** click of a button select **first** li tag, on **second** click select **second** li tag and so on...
You can see that this is not working as expected (it selects first and second tag).
Can someone help me or point me in the right direction? Here's jsFiddle link:http://jsfiddle.net/aH8w2/ Thank you!!!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addCss(){


$('ul li.first').addClass('red');

}

$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){    
addCss();
});

$("button").click(function(){    
if($('ul li.first').is('.red'))
$('ul li.first').next('li').addClass('red'); 
});

});

</script>
```

Comment: Here is jsfiddle link:  http://jsfiddle.net/aH8w2/

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle. Be sure to accept an answer when you've found something that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("button").click(function(){    

  $('.red').removeClass('red').next('li').addClass('red');

});
```

Comment: Look at Josh Smith's answer. It may be working better for you.

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev Tried this in jsFiddle and doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/joshsmith/qZLxc/2/

Comment: Yes, it assumes that at least one `.red` item exists. Yours is better :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another way, which jumps to the beginning of the list again, when the end is reached:

```
var $lis = $('ul > li');

$("button").click(function(){   
    var $selected =  $('.red').removeClass('red');
    ($selected.next().length > 0 ? $selected.next() : $lis.first()).addClass('red');
});
```

Or a bit shorter:

```
($selected.next().get(0) || $lis[0]).className += 'red';
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aH8w2/2/)

Comment: Please select the answer that helped you the most as accepted by clicking the tick outline next to it.

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/joshsmith/qZLxc/3/)**

```
$("button").click(function(){    
    if($('.red').length > 0) {
        $('.red').removeClass('red').next().addClass('red'); 
    } else {
        $('li:first').addClass('red');   
    }
});
```

You also don't need the `.first` on your first `li`. jQuery can do `li:first` which will select the first matching item.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("button").click(function(){   
var current = $('ul li.red'); 
current.first().next('li').addClass('red'); 
current.removeClass('red');
});
```

This assumes that you have at-least one `li` that is 'red'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){    
        if($('.red').length == 0 || $('.red').next().length == 0){
           $('.red').removeClass('red');
           $('.first').addClass('red');
        }else{
            $('.red').removeClass('red').next().addClass('red');
        }
    });

});
```

This takes care of the the first click as well as all subsequent clicks. Even going back to the first if you reach the end.